# Error ODBC C# Error cadena de entrada

Tags: c#, odbc, dataset

Tengo un pequeño sistema instalado en un servidor.

Lo utilizan desde 5 PC y funciona correctamente, pero desde la 6ta PC me devuelve el error.

> La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.

```
    OdbcDataAdapter daMovims = new OdbcDataAdapter(SQL, cnnDataset);
    DataSet dsMovims = new DataSet("Movims");
    daMovims.FillSchema(dsMovims, SchemaType.Source, "Movims");
    daMovims.Fill(dsMovims, "Movims");
```

En la última línea es el error, lo raro es que esta misma estructura la utilizo en otros proyectos que tengo y nunca había fallado.

Revisé la configuración del ODBC de la PC y es igual al de las demás PC donde si funciona todo correctamente.

Agradecería pudieran comentarme, llevo unos cuantos días con este problema.

Comment: a que base de datos te estas conectando?

Comment: puedes loguear que valor toma la variable SQL? porque quizas no sea un tema de la conexion sino del select que asignas, digo si es que al realizar el Fill() es donde falla

Comment: Puede ser un tema de formato de fechas... fijate si tienen la misma configuracion regional e idioma todas las pc, ¿tienen la misma version de SO?